# I have a 16 hour layover in Morocco - can I leave the airport and go back in through customs?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, layovers, morocco

I am a US citizen traveling from New York to Ghana. I have a 16 hour layover in Morocco and want to make sure that if I leave the airport I will be allowed to go back through customs to board my last flight.

Comment: Shelbey, how did it go? Where you able to leave the airport? I am considering a flight that also requires a long layover in morocco (19 hours).
I was wondering if I could leave the airport too. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Usually the problem isn't getting back *out* of the country, but getting *in* (there are exceptions to this, such as countries where [exit visas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_%28document%29#Exit_visas) are required).

According to the [Consulate General of the Kingdom of Morocco in New York](http://www.moroccanconsulate.com/visa.cfm), citizens of the USA do not need a visa to visit Morocco for a stay up to 90 days. This would allow you to leave the airport during your stopover. Be sure to allow sufficient time to return to the airport before your next flight!